# type refining in flow union, flow doesn't recognize if-statement

Tags: javascript, casting, flowtype

Well considering the following simple code:

```
/* @flow */

type A = {|
  value: {id: number} | number,
  value2: string,
|}


type B = {
  ...$Exact<A>,
  value: number,
}


function foo(b:B, add: number) {
  console.log(b.value + add);
  console.log(b.value2)
}

const v: A = {
  value: 2,
  value2: 'a',
}
if (typeof v.value === 'number') {
  foo(v);
}
```

the `typeof` should indicate that the type is refined to "number", and thus it could be an argument of `foo`. However when I test this [in a fiddle](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN4A+qYYAbgIYwCueAXBQJYAmHAdswC2AIzwAnAL5hKYASPEAaGvSasATBwDOGMZz4BzJZQnpMuAgCFSFZQDp7AEgCiADwYBjDAB5CAPiW0jCzsskKiYkomtOhQzHyenHB8YFBwcAAUwmwWCmAM3Lyh8mIAlDa07kmacDB4tvD6mbZBrGAA1HkFJQDcypV81bX1cI3Czap4aiWoJqj92vQcxGTkyi0hagEqwRpgAOQMe5HonFBg6dj4cGd048GkJGR7cuF7Zau0qRl0PTNAA), there are errors displayed. (`Cannot call`foo`with`v`bound to`b`because object type [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property`value`.`)

Answer (score 0):

Gonna recommend reading this issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4685